# Dropdownlist does not hold selected value when use pagination in .net core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Does not hold selected value `AA` while using pagination. When moving to another page, dropdownlist moves to state `All`.

Used ViewBag to store the current filter state but no luck.

No idea where to go and change the code to make it work.
Can anyone  enlighten me the way to do this.

Controller

```
Public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchText, string currentFilter, int? page)
    {

            int selectedPage = page ?? 1;
            int bypassCount = (selectedPage - 1) * _pagingOptions.PageSize;

            if (searchText != null)
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                searchText = currentFilter;

            }

            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchText;

    }
```

index

```
<form asp-action="Index" method="get">

            <select class="custom-select" asp-for="searchText" value="@(ViewBag.CurrentFilter)">
                <option value="">All</option>
                <option value="AA">AA</option>
                <option value="AE">AE</option>
                <option value="AR">AR</option>
            </select>

         <div class="col-md-12">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
         </div>                
        </form>

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr >
                <th>Resent</th>
                <th>Resent Date</th>
                <th>Created Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if (Model.Items.TotalItemCount > 0)
            {
                @foreach (var item in Model.Items.ToList())
                {                     
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => resentString)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => resentDateString)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => createdDateString)</td>
                    </tr>

                }
            }

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

            @if (Model.Items.PageCount > 1)
            {
                @Html.PagedListPager(Model.Items, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page = page, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter})
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you switch page numbers, **the searchtext passed to the Index action loses the original filtering parameters**.

```
You don't need to add the currentfilter parameter to pass it.
```

In the process of `@Html.PagedListPager`, you just need to `reassign the searchtext` to the Index action, as shown below :
(since you do not provide the content of the detailed model, I tested it with my own data)

```
public class DefaultController : Controller
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _context;
    public DefaultController(MyDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public IActionResult Index(string searchText, int? page)
    {
        int selectedPage = page ?? 1;
        // int bypassCount = (selectedPage - 1) * 4;
        var pro = _context.Resent.ToList();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
        {
            pro = pro.Where(x => x.resent == searchText).ToList();
            page = 1;
        }
        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchText;
        ViewBag.products = pro.ToPagedList(selectedPage, 4);
        return View();
    }
}
```

View:

```
<form asp-action="Index" method="get">

    <select class="custom-select col-md-4" asp-for="searchText">
        <option value="">All</option>
        <option value="AA">AA</option>
        <option value="AE">AE</option>
        <option value="AR">AR</option>
    </select>

    <div class="col-md-8">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
    </div>
</form>

<table class="table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Resent</th>
        <th>Resent Date</th>
        <th>Created Date</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.products)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.id</td>
            <td>@item.resent</td>
            <td>@item.resentDate</td>
            <td>@item.createDate</td>
        </tr>

    }


</table>
@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.products, 
    page => Url.Action("Index", "Default", new { page = page , searchText = ViewBag.CurrentFilter}))
```

Here is the result:

[image]